# iOS: Returning to main XIB from secondary XIB

Tags: objective-c, ios, xib

I am trying to change a back to the main xib after I was on a second XIB. This is the current code I am using:

```
NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Results1" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = aView;
```

I have a button on the second xib that returns back to the originating xib. When I hit the button the app crashes. I am not sure why because it does not display an error - it just crashes. Here is the code on the button on the second xib or "Results1" xib file:

```
-(IBAction)Button100:(id)sender
{
NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"main" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
self.view = aView;
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I needed to turn off Automatic Reference Counting.

Answer (score 0):

Add as subviews instead, so you can then just 'pop' the Results1 view off:

```
// in your .h
@property (strong) UIView *aView;

// replace your provided code with this
NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Results1" owner:self options:nil];
self.aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.aView];

- (IBAction)Button100:(id)sender
{
    [self.aView removeFromSuperview];
    self.aView = nil;
}
```

Just a suggestion — if you want them to 'swap', consider using the class method `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` in UIView.

Comment: It does not seem to be working, I guess I did not explain sorry, the first set of code is in one xib and the second is in another xib file when I replace the code it does not seem to work

Comment: the second part of the code is not working I am not sure why?

    [self.aView1 removeFromSuperview];
    self.aView1 = nil;

Comment: so this is what I have come up with