# Trying to pop xib (ipad) and close once its open

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a main viewController xib and depending on the buttons the user clicks it could take them to one of 4 viewControllers xib I have seen this code and seem to be having a error.

[iOS: Returning to main XIB from secondary XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893963/ios-returning-to-main-xib-from-secondary-xib)

```
- (IBAction)Button100:(id)sender
{
    [self.aView removeFromSuperview];
    self.aView = nil;
}
```

It canot find the aView in the second xib should the `@property (strong) UIView *aView;` go in the main appdeligte or just in the main .h file of the first xib?

Comment: From what You've said I think You are trying to access the reference stored in a main view controller from another view controller. The best way to remove the view from it's own controller class is: [self.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question. I have a main storyboard, how do I pop a xib over top of it and then close it again on a button push? I am new to objective c and it seemed like the question above was what I was looking for, I have 4 xib's that could be opened depending on what the person pushes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I understand that You just want to show and hide appropriate views depending on the button clicked.

One way to do it is to put this in Your root view controller:

```
-(IBAction) buttonXClicked {
    [self presentModalViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
}
```

(I assume here that You already know how to link a button with it's action, if not please read this tutorial: http://rshankar.com/different-ways-to-connect-ibaction-to-uibutton/ )

and then in Your child view:

```
-(IBAction) backButtonClicked {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Another way (though without animations) is in Your root view controller:

```
-(IBAction) buttonXClicked {
    [self.view addSubview:someViewController.view];
}
```

and in the child view:

```
-(IBAction) buttonXClicked {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I also recommend You check this tutorial on using a navigation controller (which should look better):

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2012/09/navigation-based-project-doing-it-using.html

Comment: Thank you for this information, do I have to specify in the root view controller the name of the other view controllers? I am getting a error "Use of undeclared Identifier "ViewController1" on the [self.view addSubView.ViewController1.view];

Comment: I believe You are trying to use a class as a variable. You need to initialize the view controller You want to show first: `UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"name-of-the-xib-file" bundle:nil];` and then show it like this: `[self.view addSubView:myViewController.view];`

Comment: I have it thank you I am going to mark you answer as correct! Thank you again!